# Make fire material "go over" shape

Tags: materials

I apologize if the wording is weird, English isn't my first language ^-^'

I downloaded a low poly model and wanted to play a bit, so I added a fire shader that has a certain transparency as one of the materials; it worked, but the fire was restriced to inside of the model shape. Is there a way for the fire material to keep the model's shape, but also passing a bit the original geometry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A shader displays a material only on the faces of the mesh, or inside its volume, which explains why you can't go 'over the boundaries' for the fire effect.

You could add a larger mesh with the fire shader around your initial object and it would then go beyond the first model's boundaries.

Comment: I will try that, thanks!